# How to print php array to use in javascript?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I want to print this array :

```
$arr = array("foo","foo","foo");
```

if I use
implode I will get this

```
foo,foo,foo
```

but I want :

```
"foo","foo","foo"
```

How could I do that ?

Comment: What is [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$arr = array("foo","foo","foo");
echo "\"" . implode("\",\"", $arr) . "\"";
```

Output:

```
"foo","foo","foo"
```

But if I read your title: *How to print php array to use in javascript?*

I think you want to use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), like this:

```
$arr = array("foo","foo","foo");
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Output:

```
["foo","foo","foo"]
```

You can assign this to a javascript variable if you want